# Justify Single Word divided into rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to justify one word divided into three rows with CSS and possibly jQuery.

It is in a fluid layout and the word should fill 100% of the parent div.

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFlqh.png]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #111;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 836px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 478px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.flex > span {
  width: 33.33%;
  font-size: 6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex > span:nth-child(8) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <span>S</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>R</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>N</span>
  <span>G</span>
  <span>T</span>
  <span>hidden</span>
  <span>H</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution for you:

```js
let word = "Settnrgh";
let list = word.split('');

let firstword = list[0] + list[1] + list[2];
let secondword = list[3] + list[4];
let thirdword = list[5] + list[6] + list[7];

$(".left").text(firstword);
$(".center").text(secondword);
$(".right").text(thirdword)
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 15px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent .text-div {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left text-div">

  </div>
  <div class="center text-div">

  </div>
  <div class="right text-div">

  </div>
  <div></div>

</div>
</div>
```